# How can I capture multiple computer screens and put them onto a single video stream?

Tags: screen-casting

We are looking to broadcast or record a single video stream of two desktop computers running Windows.  The software we are looking for would be able to capture the screens of the people working on it and composite them into a single video feed.

For audio, we would like to capture the computer's audio device but also ambient sounds from the room.

To summarize, we want one output feed that consists of the following:

- Source video feed from computer #1 (in a 50% rectangle)
- Source video feed #2 (in a 50% rectangle)
- Environment noise from the room (mic in)
- Source audio feed from computer #1
- Source audio feed from computer #2

So far, we have attempted to use Google Hangout, but it's impossible to get two screen shares going on at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

[UStream](http://www.ustream.tv/) has a great program that you can do that with. Your video will eighter be streamed over UStream or to a server you specify if you want that.

Comment: I clicked on the link in Google Chrome and received the warning: "www.ustream.tv contains malware. Your computer might catch a virus if you visit this site." WOT however say's the site is [OK](http://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/www.ustream.tv).

Comment: Somebody has probably set this up. http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?client=Firefox&hl=en-US&site=http://ustream.tv/

Comment: Maybe an ad did something it shouldn't. If it was, it isn't any more insecure to browse UStream than any other website with ads. Google just noted it, and thus you see the warning. It is safe.